# Rxjs execute concatMap only once

Tags: angular, rxjs, rxjs6

I have two Observables, **getUser** and **getUserAvatar**.
Both of them emits two values - cached immediately using BehaviorSubject, and real after network request.

Now code works this way:

1) Send request to get user and immediately emit cached user

2)After cached user emited, code goes inside concatMap, and execute getUserAvatar first time

3)getUserAvatar send request to server and immediately emit cached userAvatar

4)Everything is completed and cached user with cached avatar returned

5) After some time, real user returned and getUser emits value again

6) **At this step, I want to prevent call concatMap second time**, because server request already in progress, I want just go to return 'USER LOADED.

```
sendGetRequest('/user/').pipe(
        concatMap(() => {
            // HERE, after user data loaded, I have url for his avatar
            return sendGetRequest('/avatar/').pipe();
        }),
        map(() => {
            return 'USER LOADED';
        })
    )
```

Code for Server request

```
sendGetRequest(url: string, ignoreCache?: boolean): any {

    let responseSubj = new Subject();

    const cachedData = this.cache.getItemForUrl(url);
    const cacheAllowed = cachedData && !ignoreCache;
    if (cacheAllowed) {
        responseSubj = new BehaviorSubject(cachedData);
    }

    const getFromServer = this.http.get(environment.API_SERVER_URL + url, this.addAuth()).pipe(
        filter((res: any) => {

            if (cacheAllowed && JSON.stringify(cachedData) === JSON.stringify(res)) {
                responseSubj.complete();
                return false;
            }

            this.cache.setItemForUrl(url, res).then(() => {
                responseSubj.complete();
            });
            return true;
        }),
        catchError((error, caught) => {
            console.log('ERROR FROM GET REQUEST', error);
            return throwError(error);
        })
    );


    return merge(responseSubj, getFromServer);
}
```

Comment: Please add the code which executes the logic you described

Comment: I added code for function, which perform server request

Comment: What is your 6th point. It's not very clear. You are calling getUser() but not getUserAvatar() because ? Also, what is the meaning of real user?

Comment: You could use `forkJoin` instead for both requests and `as of RxJS 6.5+ we can use a dictionary of sources` which might be handy here https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/combination/forkjoin.html

Comment: You are making this way too complex ... you actually dont even need subjects ... I would help you, but your sample is way too confusing. Is there any relation between the first code section with the getUser and getUserAvatar calls, and the second section with the sendGetRequest call? Also, is there a specific reason why you are using concatMap and not mergeMap or switchMap?

Comment: I edited code. I need this way flow, because to load user avatar, first user have to be loaded. @Davy, why I don`t need subjects? I want to emit cached value as soon as someone subscribes to request.
@emkay, I'm calling getUser, because after first emit of cached getUser response, getAvatar is called. And getAvatar making backend request. After second emit from getUser(when server returns data), getAvatar will be called again, making again the same backend request. I'm not using mergeMap, because avatar depends of user.

Comment: Is the stackblitz what you were looking for?

Answer (score 1):

So, i think this is what you are after:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-2kaawf

So, as you can see, i am not declaring any Subjects to fetch the cached results. I am not saying that you should not use Subjects. You just did not need them in this case. I included a clear cache and reload button just to illustrate what you could use a subject for.

If you reload the page, you will see that the previously used data is reused. When you clear the cached however, the cached data is gone and you will see "null" after reloading.

This code will works as expected. However if you would have 2 subscriptions on the user$ observable, you will get some unexpected results. To fix those issues, look into the shareReplay operator ;)

Answer (score -1):

You should use `exhaustMap` instead of `concatMap`.

`exhaustMap` ignore other values until that observable completes.

For example,

```
fromEvent(this.saveButton.nativeElement, 'click')
.pipe(
    exhaustMap(() => this.saveCourse(this.form.value))
)
.subscribe();
```

If we now click save let's say 5 times in a row, we can see, the clicks that we made while a save request was still ongoing where ignored, as expected!

Example is from [angularuniveristy](https://blog.angular-university.io/rxjs-higher-order-mapping/) blog.

[Detailed explanation of exhaustMap](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/transformation/exhaustmap.html)